# Why can't I put Flask on Mac OS in Terminal?

Tags: python, python-venv

Following Flask Framework's install project instructions I get this on the macOS Monterey 12.7.3

```
[ningishzida-1:~/mu_code/myproject] charlesthompson% csh .venv/bin/activate.csh
prompt: Undefined variable.
[ningishzida-1:~/mu_code/myproject] charlesthompson%
```

Comment: The `activate` scripts are intended to be sourced by the current shell, not executed as scripts. You are currently running `zsh`, not `csh`: use `source .venv/bin/activate` instead.

Comment: If you *wanted* to run `csh` for whatever reason, you run `csh` first, *then* source `.venv/bin/activate.csh`.

Comment: Actually it says I'm on csh at chsh.

Comment: source .venv/bin/activate
gives: Badly placed ()'s.

Comment: *`source .venv/bin/activate.csh`. By the way, if you aren’t intentionally on csh, I would recommend switching to the default and more typical zsh.

Comment: @CharlesThompson "Badly placed ()" comes if try  to  source `activate` from `csh`.  So, try to `source .venv/bin/activate.csh`.

Comment: Could you provide a link to those instructions which say you should do this?